# Regex for parsing HTML tables?

Tags: java, html, regex

I already tried a lot of different regex but couldn't find the solution.

I need a regex to find:

```
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<tr>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>(\s*<tr>\s*<td>.*?</td>\s*</tr>)*
```

So the first `<tr>` block must contain two `<td>` tags and all following (0 or many) `<tr>` tags must only contain 1 `<td>` tag.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know but it's a task for a uni and we must use regex. Usually I do it with a HTML parser :(

Comment: Please show whoever give you such task those questions/answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454, [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166), [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747).

Comment: But just for "fun", lets work on this regex. What problems you are facing? What do you have so far?

Comment: @Pshemo My regex looks like this so far: `<tr>(.*?<td.*?>(.*?)</td>){2}.*?</tr>(.*?<tr>.*?<td>(.*?)</td>.*?</tr>)*?`

Comment: Dot `.` can't by default match line separators like `\r` or `\n`. To let it match them via `.*` compile your regex with `DOTALL` flag like `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);`. Also last `?` causes last rows to not be matched since `?` makes `*` reluctant. Consider removing it.

Comment: OR don't use dot in `.*` at all. If you want to match line separator just use `\R` instead, or `\s` which will also match other whitespaces like tabs. Using `.*` will also match extra `<td>...</td>`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yep, I used DOTALL and MULTILINE as flags. I updated the regex to: `<tr>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>(\s*<tr>\s*<td>.*?</td>\s*</tr>)*` but it's still not working.

Comment: How are you using this regex? Can you provide some code example? Can you include link to it like on https://ideone.com/?

Comment: @Pshemo Here 2 files combined: https://hastebin.com/noqovupame.java 
The input file is this page locally: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Comicverfilmungen

Comment: What is the **actual** content you are getting via `String allMoviesEnumeration = scanner.next();`? Can you post it, or preferably its fragment which will let us see actual data you are parsing along with expected results?

Comment: Here it is: https://hastebin.com/omigolanux.xml

Comment: OK so what is the expected output you want to get, and what you see instead?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

This is the regex format for extracting HTML tables from web-page source code:

```
(?is)<tr.*?>.*?(?:<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>\s*)(?=(?:<td.*?>(.*?)<\/td>)?).*?<\/tr>
```

you can apply the above format in any programming language. it depends on how dose the used language deal with regex.

Comment: `<code>`? --- Why are you escaping `/`? Java regex doesn't need that. --- What is the purpose of the `(?: )` non-capturing group?

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. I'm not an expert but I need to "count" the occurrences of the TD-Tags. How to implement that?

Answer (score -1):

Processing HTML tags with regular expressions is problematic; one should use an HTML parse if at all possible. Let's take a simple case of recognizing (fictional) tags `<a>` and `<b>`. To keep it simple we will assume that we do not have to worry about attributes on these tags or white space. We are interested in recognizing a single `<b>` tag nested within an `<a>` tag, such as:

```
<a><b>1</b></a>
```

The "obvious" but incorrect regular expression is:

```
<a><b>.*?</b></a>
```

It will match the above example, but it will also match:

```
<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>
```

Even though `.*?` is not *greedy*, it is as greedy as it needs to be in an attempt to match the rest of the input against the rest of the regular expression.

You need to replace `.*?` with something that will not scan past the closing `</b>` tag:

```
((?!</b>).)*
```

This says that as long as the next characters are not the closing `</b>` tag, scan one more character. For good measure you might also want to ensure you do not skip over the start of another `<a>` tag:

```
((?!(<a>|</b>)).)*
```

So the final regex becomes:

```
<a><b>((?!(<a>|</b>)).)*</b></a>
```

Anyway, that's the approach I have taken. Consequently, the regex for the problem at hand becomes rather complicated.

My understanding is that you are looking for a `<tr>` tag with two nested `<td>` tags followed by 0 or more `<tr>` tags with one nested `<td>` tag. If I have that straight, then the regex is:

```
"(?s)<tr[^>]*>(\\s*<td[^>]*>((?!(<tr|</td)).)*</td>\\s*){2}\\s*</tr>(\\s*<tr[^>]*>\\s*<td[^>]*>((?!(<tr|</td)).)*</td>\\s*</tr>)*"
```

The code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;

public class Test
{
    public static void doMatch (String s) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)<tr[^>]*>(\\s*<td[^>]*>((?!(<tr|</td)).)*</td>\\s*){2}\\s*</tr>(\\s*<tr[^>]*>\\s*<td[^>]*>((?!(<tr|</td)).)*</td>\\s*</tr>)*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            MatchResult m = matcher.toMatchResult();
            System.out.println("Match: " + m.group(0));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<tr>\n    <td>XYZ</td>\n    <td><tag1>abc\ndef</tag2></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n    <td>XYZ</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n    <td>XYZ</td>\n</tr>";
        Test.doMatch(s);
        s = "<tr><td>1></td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3></td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>5></td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>7</td></tr>";
        Test.doMatch(s);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Match: <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td><tag1>abc
def</tag2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
</tr>
Match: <tr><td>1></td><td>2</td></tr>
Match: <tr><td>3></td><td>4</td></tr>
Match: <tr><td>5></td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>7</td></tr>
```